ckEditor 5 Font and Ident dependencies/modules contain inline styles and violate my CSP
I am using CKEditor 5 with a custom build to include the fonts and indent modules into the basic build that exists on github.  My web environment CSP doesn't allow any inline styles or javascript.  The security policy also doesn't allow any links to external servers which is why I need the .js and .css files built to distribute with my application.
For my custom build I modified, as suggested on CKEditor's documentation (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/csp.html), to extract styles to a separate .css file during the editor building process.  When I did this the only styles extracted were those related to the themes.  This did resolve most of the inline style issues and allow the control to display properly in my page.  However, when I try to use either the indent or font features I still get a inline style error.
The error I get is:

Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked an inline style (style-src-attr) from being applied because it violates the following directive: “style-src 'self' 'nonce-MC4yNDc5NTAyNDgxMTI0Mzc4Mg==' 'report-sample'”

For the indent feature it is trying to insert margin-left or margin-right style within the javascript which is what causes the error.
My CSP is:

Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'; default-src 'self' 'nonce-" + nonce + "'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-" + nonce + "' 'report-sample'; object-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-" + nonce + "' 'report-sample'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; media-src 'self'

What is the solution for getting these features to pass with the strict "no inline" CSP?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My problem is that ckEditor contains inline styles and gives me the error I specified because my CSP does not allow for any inline javascript or styles unless they are nonced.  The I have taken the steps specified in the ckEditor documentation to remove the inline styles and place them into a styles.css file.  But, this step only works for the theme styles.  The @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font and "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent editing tools still contain inline styles.  For example when I try to indent it adds DOM style="margin-left: 80px" to the control and this violates my CSP rules for inline.

As CKEditor is usually only used in the backend, you might want to use two different CSP, one for frontend, one for backend. Latter one could be done with a subdomain, which makes your backend also more secure, if its blocked from the frontend-domain. Concerning inline-style this might not solve the problem you asked for, though.

Seems to me like you will have to add some custom downcasting (model to view) and upcasting (view to model) for your attributes.
here is an example of how to convert font-size to class instead of inline attribute.
    this.editor.conversion.for('downcast').add((dispatcher) => {
    dispatcher.on(`attribute:fontSize`,
        (evt, data, conversionApi) => {
            const modelItem = data.item;

            const consumable = conversionApi.consumable;
            //you need to make sure to consume the attribute so it doesn't get consumed 
            //in lower priority converters such as the default one
            if (!consumable.test(data.item, 'attribute:fontSize')) {
                return;
            }

            consumable.consume(data.item, 'attribute:fontSize');
            const fontSize = modelItem.getAttribute('fontSize');
            const viewItem = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement(modelItem);
            conversionApi.writer.addClass(
                `text-[${fontSize}]`,
                viewItem
            );

        }, {
            priority: 'highest'
        }
    );
})

the above downcast will generate something like
<p class="text-[14px]">test text</p>

which is compatible with tailwindCss
to upcast this (read it into ckEditor again) you'll need to do something like
this.editor.conversion.for('upcast').attributeToAttribute({
view: {
    key: 'fontSize',
},
model: {
    key: 'class',
    value: (viewElement) => {
        const classes = Array.from(viewElement.getClassNames());
        const fontSizeClass = classes.find((c) => c.includes('text-'));
        return fontSizeClass ? fontSizeClass.replace('text-', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '') : null;
    },
},
converterPriority: 'highest',
});

the above code should look for a class that start with text- and extract the font size from it and assign it to the model item as a fontSize attribute.
please note that I didn't get a chance to run the code but this is the general principle I'd use to solve such problems

Thanks for your response.  But, I am not familiar with downcasting and/or upcasting.  But the above example sounds like it is more complex than what I need.  My goal is to be able to use the ckEditor to add "indents" and "color" (ckEditor font tool) to my text.  I think the inline style issue is a bug in the ckEditor tool.

especially colors with the whole palette never work without inline style. Of course it's possible to limit the colors, the common color-plugin still uses the inline-mechanism. Concerning other plugins the critic might be justified but it depends on the plugins if they use classes or style.
